# Why was the precipitation-streamflow correlation greater in the intact catchment at Hubbard BrookI

Tags: ecology

I gave an assignment and ran a class on this data last year.

https://lifediscoveryed.org/r290/hubbard_brook_streamflow_response_to_deforestation

Its a classic small watershed experiment where streamflows and precipitation are compared for two catchment areas, one with intact tree cover, the other deforested.

Streamflow and precipitation are, unsurprisingly correlated, but this correlation is apparently much greater for intact (0.91) than deforested (0.72) watershed.

I had no explanation to offer students for this, (I'd expect the opposite) which is OK, but if I run it again I'd like to have one up my sleave.